# 'phone' is not displayed in the mail form

Tags: php, html, email

The mail is sent successfully to my domain-mail. however, the 'phone' is not sent in the mail content.
The content of the mail comes like this.

**You have been contacted by yourname with regards, their additional message
is as follows.
"What I want to say~~ "
You can contact yourname via email, omain@domain or via phone**

What's the problem?

```
<form method="post" action="php/contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
<input name="name" type="text" id="name"  onClick="this.select()" value="Name" >
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" onClick="this.select()" value="E-mail" >            
<input type="text"  name="phone" id="phone" onClick="this.select()" value="Phone" /> 

<textarea name="comments"  id="comments" onClick="this.select()" >Message</textarea>
<button type="submit"  id="submit"  data-top-bottom="transform: translateY(-50px);" data-bottom-top="transform: translateY(50px);"><span>Send Message </span></button>                                                                                                      
</form>
```

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

/*
*  CONFIGURE EVERYTHING HERE
*/

// an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
$fromEmail = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$fromName = $_REQUEST['name'] ;

$to_Email = "my@domain.com";

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); 
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone   = $_POST['phone'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">You must enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"> Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($phone) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter a valid phone number.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!is_numeric($phone)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Phone number can only contain digits.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter your message.</div>';
    exit();
} 

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}


// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

//$address = "my@domain.com";
$address = "my@domain.com";


// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

$e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';


// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name with regards, their additional message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email or via phone $phone";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h3>Email Sent Successfully.</h3>";
    echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

It seems to me that this needs to be corrected...
$e_reply =

Comment: Probably, you're not initialising `$phone` when you're initialising the other variables that you're using (`$name`,`$email`). You don't show that code so it's difficult to say.

Comment: I've uploaded all the PHP code.

Comment: I can't see anything obvious. Can you successfully print the value of `$phone` before your validation begins?

Comment: Your HTML appears to have two different `<form>` tags pointing at different PHP files. Are you using the right one?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text"  name="phone" id="phone" onClick="this.select()" value="Phone" />
```

by removing "/" at the end of the tag may help you.